# identifying dynamic pages (created by PHP from database)

Tags: php, content-management-system, codeigniter-2

*In case this question has been asked before just refer me to the answer and I shall be greatful.. it's a very common problem however I have not been able to find solution form google*

I am developing a website in PHP using codeigniter. I have articles /Posts. These posts are located in a database and when ever a user demands to see an Article, all its relevant data is pulled from database using a unique "Content_id" and a page is presented to user dynamically. 
However once the data is dispatched to the view and an html page is created from that page I have no way of finding which "Content_id" was used in generating that page. Now in case user comments on that page I dont know which "content_id" to save in the comments table along with this comment so that next time when this article is displayed then all the relevant comments can also be displayed.

**some of the solutions that I thought are as follows**

1. Can I use session to store this data? (However I am not using sessions for those users who are not logged in ... So can I use sessions for all users )
2. Will using a form on the page with hidden fields be a viable option...
   How do Wordpress or other CMS are handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, your table needs four columns:

1. Unique row number
2. Content
3. Post number
4. Post date (timestamp)
5. The unique row number is the primary key. Auto_increment it.
6. The content is the posted message.
7. The post number is the row number of the post that starts the conversation.  Make it the same as the row number in the conversation's first post. It is the row number of the post being responded to. All responses to the conversation will have the same post number.
8. The post date is a timestamp. It permits you to organize the order of the posts in a particularized conversation.

Each conversation, or sub_conversation, follows this routine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the post id is passed as a GET variable anyway. If not, a hidden input is fine.

Comment: Dear Friend the hidden field can be ammended by the user thus does not look fine to me.. More over how does Content management systems solve this problem. The point is once the content are displayed to user they are converted from dynamic to plain html then where is the content_is stored?

Comment: Yes, but what do you care? Even if he does edit the value of the hidden field, one of two things will happen, either he'll try to post the comment to a page which doesn't exist, in which case, nothing will happen. Or he'll post to a page that does exist, and his comment will be posted there. Not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks Mr Truth...Based on your input I think I should send the content_id with each page as a hidden field encrypted as md5. However still is this the Way Wordpress implements it??? if you can plz answer that. Thanks a lotttttt for your input

Comment: @BilalTariq: Wordpress usually passes the ID along with the GET variables if I remember correctly. They also use a single point of entry (all requests are redirected to index.php, and the index.php does its including based on the GET variables from the rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

I am Very sory to Know that no one answerd my question except one persone

Any ways here is the solution that I have figured out in 1 sentence **

> The pages are not required to be numbered But the content needs to be numbered... thus each content (Article, post etc) has  a content id and that id needs to be considered.

**